# Using class in smarty templates

Tags: php, smarty

I am migrating from clean php views to smarty, and I have a problem converting the following template into smarty:

```
<?php
   use \framework\core;
?>

<h1><?= Core::translate('some string to translate'); ?></h1>
```

So I want to use some class that's loaded via autoloader, and then use its translate method. How can I do that in smarty?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this same task in one of my older projects using Smarty API extension:

```
// register additional smarty modifiers for I18N 
$this->smarty->register_block("translate", array($this, "smarty_i18n_translate"));
// better alias
$this->smarty->register_block("_", array($this, "smarty_i18n_translate"));


// translation function
public function smarty_i18n_translate($params, $content, &$smarty, &$repeat)
{
    if (isset($content))
    {
        if (isset($params['resourceID']))
        {
            $resourceID = $params['resourceID'];
            unset($params['resourceID']);
        }
        else
            $resourceID = NULL;

        // setting context vars if specified
        foreach ($params as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->setContextVar($key, $val);
        }

        // Core::translate($content); ?
        return $this->translate($content, $resourceID);
    }

    return '';
}
```

This allows writing in views (I used `{?` as smarty tag delimiter):

```
<span class="label">{?_?}Operation type{?/_?}:</span>
```

One note: this was for some pretty ancient version of Smarty, they may have changed details of API, but it seems `register` methods are still there.

Btw in the docs there is this same problem illustrated as example: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.register.block.tpl

Comment: nice :) do you need to register and create this per function? or per object/class?

Comment: Well, you may see this as a syntax extension, which is orthogonal to the implementation. If you mean, could it be done that we call object methods using tags - it can be done in variety of ways. For example - pass the name in attribute of tag/block and then call this as method on whatever, passing block content as parameter.

Comment: ahh i see. thanks for this. I will try it next time.(im maintaining an old system that uses this templating so this is good to know)

Comment: You should know why templating is popular, even now. Templating allows getting rid of boilerplating, and better view/business logic separation. Of course Smarty isn't best, there are HAML, etc, etc, taking conciseness to the next level, but even Smarty in my opinion is better than raw PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic/way, hope you might get some idea..

```
<?php
   $my_obj = new MyClass();

   $smarty->left_delimeter('{{');
   $smarty->right_delimeter('}}');

   $smarty->assign('my_obj', $my_obj);
   $smarty->display('your.html');
?>
```

Then on your html

```
<h1>{{ $my_obj->translate('some string to translate'); }}</h1>
```

Comment: And without php tags in the template? And if it's static method? And without creating new object?

Comment: And without php tags in the template? Ans: the reason of using templating is for us to separate the server-side code(in our case; php) and the client side codes(html) for cleaner code

Comment: What if I have a lot of different methods in my templates and dont want to assign lots of objects in every method?

Comment: If you have this need kind of globally throughout views, you may create resource, function or modifier, which will allow you to create custom tags. Take a look at http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/api.register.function.tpl

Comment: why not process all your data in the PHP and assign the final variables (the variables to be displayed) to smarty variables then display it. templates are for displaying, not processing. if you want some processes, you may do it using javascript

Comment: @Ceeee I tend to disagree, some tasks conceptually belong to views, such as formatting, sanitizing, translating.

Comment: @dmitry yes you can create functions too in smarty. but this answer if you dont want to create custom functions :)

Comment: @dmitry yes, but you use javascript? :D

Comment: @Ceeee Well, I don't understand what javascript has to do with this question.

Comment: @dmitry alrighty then. my answer might not be the best, but it can also give the op some idea :D just trying to help